# DocuSign: How do I set the page number for a Sign tab in a Word doc using the API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending DocuSign a Word doc to users via the API.

There are 7 pages in the doc file and a signature column is available on 7th page. But the sign here field is showing on the first page.

How should I set the sign here field? It should be on the 7th page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please "check" the best answer that you receive to your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you are specifying the pageNumber when placing the signature tab via the REST API:

```
"tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [{
                "xPosition":"50",
                "yPosition":"50",
                "documentId":"1",
                "pageNumber":"1"
                }]                                                                      
        }
```